# Letting SQL timestamp data when inserting it through python?

Tags: python, sql

I have a python script that reads logs and inserts the logs into a SQL DB(through python).  Is there a way that SQL can automatically timestamp the logs when they are inserted so I don't have to read the date and time from the logs in my script?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, `TIMESTAMP`. Without knowing the specific SQL technology, it's not possible to say exactly how it is defined, though

Comment: If you let SQL do it automatically, it will be the time that the script was run, not the time from the log message. Is that really what you want?

Comment: The script runs continuously while the server is on for months at a time, so I don't think so? So timestamp wouldn't work?

Comment: Unless a significantly high amount of precision is needed in your timestamps, or there is a lot of latency between Python and SQL, I would let SQL do the timestamp, probably stored in UTC.

Answer (score 0):

you could put a column in your database , this

```
date_registered TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

or you could add it in python like another value to the insert

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now()
```